# Postgres COPY command with literal delimiter

Tags: postgresql, copy, delimiter

I was trying to import a CSV file into a **PostgreSQL** table using the *COPY* command. The delimiter of the *CSV* file is comma (,). However, there's also a text field with a comma in the value. For example:

```
COPY schema.table from '/folder/foo.csv' delimiter ',' CSV header
```

Here's the content of the `foo.csv` file:

```
Name,Description,Age
John,Male\,Tall,30
```

How to distinguish between the literal comma and the delimiter?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The problem is that that's not really CSV. CSV expects delimiter characters to be quoted, and normal CSV doesn't allow for escaping delimiters. See Clodoaldo's answer.

Answer (score 5):

To have the `\` to be recognized as a escape character it is necessary to use the text format

```
COPY schema.table from '/folder/foo.csv' delimiter ',' TEXT
```

But then it is also necessary to delete the first line as the `HEADER` option is only valid for the `CSV` format.