# How to import table from PostgreSQL to SAP Hana?

Tags: postgresql, hana, postgresql-copy, hana-sql-script

I'm trying to export data from `PostgreSQL` and import it into `SAP Hana`. The problem which is `'\n'` i.e. line breaks are getting automatically removed from the TEXT data.

Example:

```
A 1,750 word essay is 11 to 12 paragraphs.
A 2,000 word essay is 13 to 14 paragraphs.
A 2,500 word essay is 16 to 17 paragraphs.
A 3,000 word essay is 20 paragraphs.
```

Is becoming

```
A 1,750 word essay is 11 to 12 paragraphs.A 2,000 word essay is 13 to 14 paragraphs.A 2,500 word essay is 16 to 17 paragraphs.A 3,000 word essay is 20 paragraphs.
```

I'm using below commands:

PostgreSQL

```
\COPY table_name TO 'path\data.csv' WITH CSV DELIMITER ',';
```

Hana

```
IMPORT FROM CSV FILE path
INTO table_name
WITH RECORD DELIMITED BY '\n'
FIELD DELIMITED BY '\t'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"';
```

Answer (score 0):

To have the `\` to be recognized as a `escape character` it is necessary to use the text format.

```
COPY table_name  from 'path\data.csv' delimiter ',' TEXT
```

Source :
[Postgres COPY command with literal delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26160816/postgres-copy-command-with-literal-delimiter)

Comment: My question was export from PostgreSQL. I've data in the table with line breaks(\n) in text fields. It should get exported with line break between texts. That is \n will not be there after getting exported from PostgreSQL

Comment: Exactly , But when we copy using the copy command , It should understand the \n as line breaks , In order to do that we have to copy it as TEXT , So that you can get the line breaks in the data too, Did you try copying the data and check how the data is ?

Comment: That command is not working - ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(3). I've data with a field which has ',' as field data. That might be the reason.

Comment: try this will export with line breaks, psql yourdatabase -c "COPY (SELECT * FROM table_to_export) TO STDOUT" > data.csv

Answer (score 0):

Instead of exporting and importing CSV files, you could use [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/), which supports both - SAP HANA and PostgreSQL.

An instruction for moving data between dbms can be found here:
https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/Data-migration